# How to set mysql query and php code to ignore value 0 and calculate other rows

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

How to set mysql query and php code, I have this mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ocene` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `predmeti` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ocena1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ocena2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ocena3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ocena4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ocena5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ocena6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 CHARSET=utf8;
```

so it takes the following values for the **ocena1 - ocena6 can range from 0 to 5**. For example, if the:

```
ocena1 = 5
ocena2 = 4
ocena3 = 0
ocena4 = 0
ocena5 = 0
ocena6 = 2
```

The function should ignore all those rows that have a value of 0, and in this case, the sum of 11 to be shared with 3. I tried everything, but I did not succeed. Thanks in advance.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","evidencija_ocena");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    $sql = "SELECT predmeti,( ocena1 + ocena2 + ocena3 + ocena4 + ocena5 + ocena6) AS prosek FROM ocene group by id";

    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
      printf ("%s (%s) <br />",$row[0],$row[1]);
      }
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }


  $sql = "SELECT  SUM(prosek) FROM ocene";   
  if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Print out result
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "PROSEK" . $row['SUM(predmeti)'] . "" ;
       echo "<br />";
}
  }

  mysqli_close($con);
```

And:

```
$brojOcena = 0
$suma = 0
if($ocena1 > 0) {
    $suma += $ocena1;
    $brojOcena += 1;
}

if($ocena2 > 0) {
    $suma += $ocena2;
    $brojOcena += 1;
}

if($ocena3 > 0) {
    $suma += $ocena3;
    $brojOcena += 1;
}

...

$prosek = $suma / $brojOcena
```

Comment: *I tried everything* - show us your attempts and we'll try to help you

Comment: if the values can only be 0..5, why did you define the fields as varchar(255) I wonder?

Comment: how's your input ? You could use an array_sum($input) and array_map(input) 
 with the same input splitting by count($array)

Comment: Why don't you use null instead of 0 when your variable should not be passed?

Comment: I set up my code

Comment: What's the point of `GROUP BY id`? `id` is the primary key, there can't be multiple rows with the same `id`.

Comment: `SUM(prosek)` can't work, there's no `prosek` column in the table. You can't refer to an alias from a previous query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the number of non-zero columns, you can do:

```
SELECT predmeti,
    (ocena1 != '0') + (ocena2 != '0') + (ocena3 != '0') + (ocena4 != '0') + (ocena5 != '0') + (ocena6 != '0') AS prosek_count,
    ocena1 + ocena2 + ocena3 + ocena4 + ocena5 + ocena6 AS prosek
FROM ocene
```

A condition expression is `1` if it's true, `0` if it's false, and you can add these together to get the count.

Comment: YES!!! Ingenious. If you can help me to php code to divide the sum of `prosek` with the number of rows where the value is greater than 0, example: the `prosek` is 25, that is 5 rows, it means 25/5 = 5.00

Comment: Put this into a subquery, and do `SELECT prosek/COUNT(*) FROM (subquery) x GROUP BY prosek`